# Precompile assets not loading properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

My application has a lot of 3rd party js/css files. We sped up the deploy by compiling these files into `external-[hash].js` and `external-[hash].css` (So Rails don't have to compile these files on every single deploy)

And loaded them like this in `application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "external", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "external" %>
```

These two files are under `/public/assets/`. This was working fine when we are on Rails 4. We are currently trying to upgrade to Rails 5, and these two files are not loading properly.

I changed the tags into below and in the chrome console, these files appear to have been loaded properly.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/external-[hash]", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/external-[hash]" %>
```

[image: chrome console source screenshot]

However, when I add in the application style/js tags below the external tags

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I keep getting the error

```
Error: "img" failed to @extend ".img-responsive".
       The selector ".img-responsive" was not found.
       Use "@extend .img-responsive !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

Looking into the `external-[hash].css`, I am able to see the `.img-responsive` selector defined. So, it seems like Rails 5 does not properly load these two files?

I'm currently using Rails 5.1.7, Ruby 2.4.2

I also tried adding `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` to environment files.

Here are how I've setup the external files.

I have an `external.js`, and `external.scss`, these files live under `app/assets`.

Inside application.js/css, I added `stub external` to both, so when the rails application deploys, it ignored the external files. I would run `RAILS_ENV=external_assets rails assets:precompile` and commit those files to git, expecting them to be loaded first.

Example external.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.readyselector
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require moment
//= require d3
//= require c3
//= require jsgrid.min
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

external.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require c3
 *= require jsgrid.min
 *= require jsgrid-theme.min
 */

 @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
 @import "font-awesome";
 @import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
 @import 'bootstrap';
 @import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Answer (score 1):

Try some below commands

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:clean
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:clobber
```

And change in production

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then again run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

Comment: Compile as `true` will tell the web server to use Sprockets to load the assets, and not load them from the `public/` folder.  Perhaps it isn't that big of a deal, but I've read in many places that it's linked with bad performance and is the entire reason one would precompile assets in the first place.  You precompile them so you don't have to compile them...